# How to retrieve a property of a class by filtering an observable collection by using other properties?

Tags: c#, class, uwp

I am working on a UWP app on VS2015 Community and I have made a class Candidate and another class CandidateManager. In CandidateManager class I created a method getCandidateByCategory to sort out candidate by their category number and serial number. I have called the method on the ScienceAndITClub.Xaml.cs page but now I am having problem retrieving the name property of the filtered item (to set it as the content of RBcand1 radiobutton), there's the red line under '.' which shows the error "Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'". Also, there's always only one candidate with a specific set of category number and serial number.

Here's the Science&ITClub.Xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class ScienceAndITClub : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates;

    public ScienceAndITClub()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        CandidateManager.GetAllCandidates(Candidates);


        var v = new Candidate();
        v = (CandidateManager.GetCandidatesByCategory(Candidates, CandidateCategoryNo.I, CandidateSNo.I).ToList<Candidate>);
        string cand1name = v.Name;
        RBcand1.Content = cand1name;
    }

    private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here's the code of candidate class, i.e. Candidate.cs:

```
public class Candidate
{
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public CandidateSNo S_no { get; set; }
    public CandidateCategoryNo Category_no { get; set; }

}

public enum CandidateCategoryNo
{
    I,
    II,
    III,
    IV,
    V,
    VI
}

public enum CandidateSNo
{
    I,
    II,
    III
}
```

Here's the code of CandidateManager class, i.e., CandidateManager.cs:

> ```
>  class CandidateManager
> {
>     public static void GetAllCandidates(ObservableCollection<Candidate>   candidates)
>     {
>         var allCandidates = getCandidate();
>         candidates.Clear();
>         allCandidates.ForEach(p => candidates.Add(p));
>     }
>      public static void GetCandidatesByCategory(ObservableCollection<Candidate> candidates, CandidateCategoryNo candidateCategory, CandidateSNo Sno)
>     {
>         var allCandidates = getCandidate();
>         var filteredCandidates = allCandidates.Where(p => p.Category_no == candidateCategory).ToList();
>         filteredCandidates = allCandidates.Where(p => p.S_no == Sno).ToList();
>         candidates.Clear();
>         filteredCandidates.ForEach(p => candidates.Add(p));
>     }
>     private static List<Candidate> getCandidate()
>     {
>         var _candidate = new List<Candidate>();
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Science and IT Club", Name = "A" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Science and IT Club", Name = "B" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Science and IT Club", Name = "C" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.II, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Dance Club", Name = "D" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.II, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Dance Club", Name = "E" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.II, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Dance Club", Name = "F" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.III, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Music Club", Name = "G" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.III, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Music Club", Name = "H" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.III, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Music Club", Name = "I" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.IV, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Social Service Club", Name = "J" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.IV, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Social Service Club", Name = "K" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.IV, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Social Service Club", Name = "L" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.V, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Sports Club", Name = "M" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.V, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Sports Club", Name = "N" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.V, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Sports Club", Name = "O" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.VI, VoteCount = 0, Category = "School Captain", Name = "P" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.VI, VoteCount = 0, Category = "School Captain", Name = "Q" });
>         _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.VI, VoteCount = 0, Category = "School Captain", Name = "R" });
>         return _candidate;
>     }
> }
> ```

Also, in this program, I am going to take the candidates' names as input from user (I haven't designed that function yet so I put all the names as just alphabets), so can you please also tell me that how to convert an input from textbox to the name property of a candidate.

Hope you will help ... Thanks, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in the collection object and modifying it in the "filtering."  So, in your case, you could call the method, which will alter ScienceAndITClub page's collection - so read from it.  If you use .FirstOrDefault(), it will give you the first entry (you are expecting only one), or null if there is nothing in the collection.

That should address your error concern.  However, there are more issues you will see once you start getting the data back.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates = new ObservableCollection<Candidate>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        CandidateManager.GetAllCandidates(Candidates);

        //this line alters the Candidates collection
        CandidateManager.GetCandidatesByCategory(Candidates, CandidateCategoryNo.I, CandidateSNo.I);
        //now that the method is done, you can use the Candidates collection to get the results
        var v = Candidates.FirstOrDefault();    //will get first candidate, or null if collection is empty
        string cand1name = v.Name;
        RBcand1.Content = cand1name;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I had a little bit of time on lunch, so I put together something that you can think about as you develop your project.  Let the CandidateManager manage the candidates and be the source of the data.  In a real world app, I would go the MVVM route and create repository and service layers... but this should get you started.  Change out to ObservableCollection if your application requires it.

```
public class CandidateManager
{
    //first time CandidateManager is used, it will populate backing store
    static CandidateManager()
    {
        //initialize data collection
        Candidates = new List<Candidate>();
        GetCandidateData().ForEach(p => Candidates.Add(p));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Backing Store
    /// </summary>
    private static List<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns all candidates
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<Candidate> GetAllCandidates()
    {
        return Candidates;      
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns all candidates for a specified category
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="candidateCategory"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<Candidate> GetCandidatesByCategory(CandidateCategoryNo candidateCategory)
    {
        return Candidates.Where(c => c.Category_no == candidateCategory).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns specific candidate based on unique category/sno combination.
    /// Returns null if no match
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="candidateCategory"></param>
    /// <param name="Sno"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Candidate GetCandidateByCategoryAndSno(CandidateCategoryNo candidateCategory, CandidateSNo Sno)
    {
        return Candidates.Where(c => c.S_no == Sno && c.Category_no == candidateCategory).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// data creation
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<Candidate> GetCandidateData()
    {
        var _candidate = new List<Candidate>();
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Science and IT Club", Name = "A" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Science and IT Club", Name = "B" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Science and IT Club", Name = "C" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.II, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Dance Club", Name = "D" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.II, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Dance Club", Name = "E" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.II, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Dance Club", Name = "F" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.III, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Music Club", Name = "G" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.III, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Music Club", Name = "H" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.III, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Music Club", Name = "I" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.IV, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Social Service Club", Name = "J" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.IV, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Social Service Club", Name = "K" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.IV, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Social Service Club", Name = "L" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.V, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Sports Club", Name = "M" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.V, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Sports Club", Name = "N" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.V, VoteCount = 0, Category = "Sports Club", Name = "O" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.VI, VoteCount = 0, Category = "School Captain", Name = "P" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.VI, VoteCount = 0, Category = "School Captain", Name = "Q" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.VI, VoteCount = 0, Category = "School Captain", Name = "R" });
        return _candidate;
    }
}
```

Then, in your UI code, just use the manager to retrieve the data.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var c = CandidateManager.GetCandidateByCategoryAndSno(CandidateCategoryNo.II, CandidateSNo.II);
    RBcand1.Content = c?.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark but now on the line "candidates.Clear();" of CandidateManager.cs, it shows an error while debugging : "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SchoolElection.exe but was not handled in user code
"

Comment: that is because it is never assigned to... I overcame this with the "= new ObservableCollection<Candidate>(); line in my sample above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, I know I've wasted enough of your time, but would you please tell me what is the code in the GetCandidateData method.

Comment: It is in the post... it is the same as your getCandidate() method... i just renamed it so it made more sense to me.